# js scope and the window object?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Dog(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.bark = function() {
    this.name += " hello";
    console.log(this.name);
    (function() {
      this.name += "a";
      console.log(this.name);
    })();
  }
};
let dog = new Dog("tep", 2);
dog.bark();
```

can anyone please tell me what happened here? when I open the console, It print 2 lines which are

- tep hello
- a

> every time I reload the page, it continue add the 'a' in line 2, and I
> saw in the window object, there is property "name"

- tep hello
- aa

Comment: Since it's 2020 why not use `class` instead of the old-school `function`-as-Object style?

Comment: Hint: What scope does your inner anonymous function run in when called?

Comment: You can fix this by using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which preserves `this` binding.

Comment: I'm new and i'm reading the headfirst javascript :))

Comment: The 2014 version? If so, that book is no longer relevant and isn't worth using. ES6 has dramatically changed how JavaScript works and how it *should* be used. The MDN site has some [fantastic resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript) on learning JavaScript that should be your first stop. For any other references, be *sure* that they cover ES6 properly, and it's not just some additional chapter at the end that hand-waves over it.

Comment: Make sure to use strict mode and get the relevant exception

Comment: thank you sir! i'm trying to understand the es5 and how it differs from ES6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside an anonymous function you lose the `this` binding, so it just defaults to something. In a browser it's effectively `window`.

To fix this you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as those preserve `this` bindings:

```
 (() => {
    this.name += "a";
    console.log(this.name);
 })();
```

Creating these sorts of closure-functions is not something you want to do without an exceptionally good reason, though. They're normally used to ensure variables don't "escape", but with the introduction of `let` and `const` it's far less likely you'll *have* to use one.

In this case there's absolutely no advantage to using one, you're not making any locals anyway.